# How to display Linq query in DataGridView cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

How to display Linq query in DataGridView cell?

i want to display query in BoundField look at a picture in comment

I want to change this

[image: pic1]

to change this pic

[image: pic2]

back end:

```
var show = (from u in database.tbl_SubUser
            orderby u.SubUserID descending
            select new
            {
                u.UserID_FK,
                u.Name,
                u.SubUserID,
                u.Day
            }).ToList();
e.Result = show;
```

front :

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grdShowListSubUser" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataSourceID="dsshowlistSubuser2" runat="server" CssClass="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-responsive" OnRowCommand="grdShowListSubUser_RowCommand" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="AliceBlue" AllowPaging="true">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ردیف" HeaderStyle-BackColor="Moccasin">

                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblRowCount" runat="server" Text='<%#Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>

                                </asp:TemplateField>

                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="نام شعبه" NullDisplayText="" HeaderStyle-BackColor="Moccasin" />

                                <asp:BoundField DataField="day" HeaderText="مدت اعتبار" NullDisplayText="" HeaderStyle-BackColor="Moccasin" />

                                   <asp:BoundField DataField="UserID_FK" HeaderText="زیرمجموعه"  NullDisplayText="" HeaderStyle-BackColor="Moccasin" />




                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="عملیات" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#33cccc">
                                    <ItemTemplate>

                                       <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnDelete" runat="server" Text="حذف" CssClass="btn btn-danger btn-xs" CommandName="DoDelete" OnClientClick="return confirm('با حذف این کاربر کلیه اطلاعات مرتبط حذف خواهد شد .ایا میخواهید این کاربر حذف شود؟')" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("SubUserID") %>'></asp:LinkButton>




                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnEdit" runat="server" Text="ویرایش" CssClass="btn btn-info btn-xs" CommandName="DoEdit" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("SubUserID")%>'></asp:LinkButton>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
```

Comment: http://uupload.ir/files/tunt_111.jpg

Comment: http://uupload.ir/files/flv_222.jpg

Comment: How are you populating the grid in the first place? Also, I have no idea what the column headers are in the grid in relation to the select statement in your query. Can you reproduce in English?

Comment: @gilliduck can you help how to display linq query in cell?

Comment: As gilliduck mentioned above you need to place the code for grid description and how you are  binding...it looks like your gridview column Name is interchanged with subuserid or userid_fk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try column and table names editing

```
        var show = (from u in database.tbl_SubUser
                join shop in database.tbl_Shop on u.UserID_FK equals shop.ID
                orderby u.SubUserID descending
                select new
                {
                    u.UserID_FK,
                    u.Name,
                    u.SubUserID,
                    u.Day,
                    ShopName = shop.Name

                }).ToList();
    e.Result = show;
```